# Avoid linking against std::_v2 symbol

Tags: c++, linux, std, clang++, abi

I am using Clang++ 10 under Ubuntu 20.04 to compile a certain shared library that will be loaded within the main program, and after recently integrating it with [ghc::filesystem](https://github.com/gulrak/filesystem) (for a C++11 compatible `filesystem` implementation), starting the program arises a library load link error: `undefined symbol: _ZNSt3_V215system_categoryEv`.

I found out the compile time linking process points STD to the newer internal `std::_v2` namespace implementation, from system's `libstdc++`, as I've double checked:

```
adrian@PC-Adrian:~$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep system_category
_ZSt15system_categoryv
_ZNSt3_V215system_categoryEv
```

The program (a game server) ships an embedded older libstdc++ in its `bin` directory, with this symbol's search result:

```
adrian@PC-Adrian:~/steamcmd/server_base/bin$ strings libstdc++.so.6 | grep system_category
_ZSt15system_categoryv
```

So, the library is looking for the `std::_V2::system_category()` symbol instead of the supposedly older `std::system_category()` one.

Given the system's `libstdc++` already provides the old STD symbol, could this issue be easily solved with any compiler flag or such? I've tried passing `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` (as I perceived that could make it) to no avail. Although I could get more missing symbols errors after fixing this one.

Comment: Fundamentally, you cannot run against an older version of the library that you link against. Try installing the older library and linking against it ... or better, try just using a newer version at runtime; libstdc++ has very good ABI compatibility.